# Adapting the beameroutertheme to the beamerinnertheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, structure

It's about putting the finishing touches on my own beamer theme. I have more or less halfway managed to create a design for the beameroutertheme.sty, but it has shifted in comparison to the innertheme. I would like to have the spacing of the red bar and the logo aligned as it is on the front page (in terms of length). Unfortunately, any attempts to change it always destroy the design. Unfortunately, I have very little or hardly any experience with tikz and it is only thanks to the community here that I have come this far.

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=169,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage {mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

%beamertheme.sty
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=2em, dp = 1em]{foot}
        \hspace*{1em}
        {\normalsize \inserttitle}\hfill{\normalsize \insertauthor, \insertdate} \hfill{\normalsize \insertpagenumber}
        \hspace*{1em}   
    \end{beamercolorbox}}


%beamercolortheme.sty
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{framtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}


%beamerinnertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {\hspace{4cm}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
        \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
        \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.5cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
         \begin{scope}
            \clip ([yshift=3cm]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
                \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
            \else
                \node[inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=1.5cm]current page.center) {\inserttitlegraphic};
            \fi     
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

%beameroutertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{test}[1][]
{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=1.2cm]{frametitle} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
            \fill[color=green] (0,0) rectangle(2.95,1.1); %5.2 old
            \fill[color=red] (3.05,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth-100,1.1);
            %           \fill[red] (3.05,1.15) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.8);
            \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            {\node at (\the\paperwidth-50,0.61){\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};%
                \node[anchor=west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.55){\insertframetitle};}%
            \else%
            {\node at (\the\paperwidth-50,0.61){\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};%
                \node[anchor= west, white,font=\large] at (3.2,0.75){\insertframetitle};%
                \node[anchor= west, white,font=\small] at (3.2,0.35){\insertframesubtitle};}%
            \fi
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=5.2ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
            \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
}



\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,very thick,text=white]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=white]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,very thick,text=blue]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=blue]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \fi
}

%End of beameroutertheme

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \section{Sec 1}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \blindtext
    \end{frame}
    \section{Sec 2}
    \begin{frame}{Title 2}
        \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
        \blindtext
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
aspectratio=169,%
]{beamer}

\usepackage {mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\title{TITLE}
\author{NAME}
\institute{INSTITUT}
\date{DATE}

%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

%beamertheme.sty
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth, ht=2em, dp = 1em]{foot}
        \hspace*{1em}
        {\normalsize \inserttitle}\hfill{\normalsize \insertauthor, \insertdate} \hfill{\normalsize \insertpagenumber}
        \hspace*{1em}   
    \end{beamercolorbox}}


%beamercolortheme.sty
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section in toc}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{framtitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{section}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=gray}
\setbeamercolor*{foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}

\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\small}

%beamerinnertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{test}[1][]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
        \node[fill=blue,minimum height=1cm,text width=\paperwidth] at ([yshift=2.5cm]current page.south) {\hspace{4cm}\usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle};
        \fill[color=green] (current page.south west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.9);
        \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.9cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.3cm] at ([yshift=0.95cm]current page.south) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor\par\vskip0.1cm \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{author}\insertdate};
        \node[anchor=south east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
         \begin{scope}
            \clip ([yshift=3cm]current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
            \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\empty%
                \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=3cm]current page.south) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-16x9}};
            \else
                \node[inner sep=0cm] at ([yshift=1.5cm]current page.center) {\inserttitlegraphic};
            \fi     
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}   
}

%beameroutertheme.sty
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{weincampus}[1][]
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
        \fill[color=green] ([yshift=-1.7cm]current page.north west) rectangle ++(2.95,1.2);
        \node[fill=red,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=\paperwidth-6.3cm] at ([yshift=-1.1cm]current page.north) {\hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertframetitle\par
        \hspace{0.9cm}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle};
        \node[anchor=north east, inner sep =0.1cm] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
    \vskip1.2cm
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=5.2ex,dp=0.125ex]{palette}%
            \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{\hskip0pt plus1filll}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
    }
}



\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,very thick,text=white]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=blue,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=white]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}{%
    \if\insertsectionheadnumber1
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,very thick,text=blue]{\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \else
    \tikz\node[draw=blue,fill=white,shape=signal,signal from=west, signal to=east,very thick,text=blue]     {\insertsectionhead\hskip.3cm};
    \fi
}

%End of beameroutertheme

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \section{Sec 1}
    \begin{frame}{Title}
        \blindtext
    \end{frame}
    \section{Sec 2}
    \begin{frame}{Title 2}
        \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
        \blindtext
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```